# PHP file upload allowing only specified extensions

Tags: php, file-upload

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. My if statements arent working, its like it doesnt recognise any file type at all.....

```
$file_name = validateInput($_FILES['file']['name']);
$temp_name = validateInput($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

//get file extension
$base = basename($file_name);
$extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

    //allowed file types
    $allowed_extensions = array(".doc", "docx", ".pdf", ".png");

//check if attachment exist

if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){

    function validateInput($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;   
    }

    $file_name = validateInput($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $temp_name = validateInput($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    //get file extension
    $base = basename($file_name);
    $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

    //allowed file types
    $allowed_extensions = array(".doc", "docx", ".pdf", ".png");

    //check if uploaded file is allowed
    if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)){

        //email essentials
        //$from = $email_address;
        $to = 'info@something.com';
        $subject = 'Applicant Application - '.$query;
        $message = $html_email;

        //handling the file
        $file = $temp_name;
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

        //standard mail headers
        $headers = "From: ".$forenames." ".$surname."\r\n";
        //$headers = "Reply-To: $to \r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

        //declaring that we have muliple kinds of email(i.e content and attachment)
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

        //plain text or html part
        $headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

        //attachment part
        $headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

        //send the mail(without message, as msg is already in header)
        if(mail($to, $subject, "", $headers)){
            $success = true;
        } else {
                    echo "<script>
                    alert('Failed to send the message. File type not allowed');
                    </script>";
        }


    } else {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Failed to send the message. File type not allowed');
        </script>";
    }

}//attachment check
```

I would also like to know the best way of limiting file size.

Thanks,

Wale

Comment: You have many `if` conditions. Which one is not working?

Comment: For getting file extensions use $current_ext = preg_replace("/.*\.([^.]+)$/","\\1", $filename);

Comment: the best ways to get the file extension is to use the pathinfo function or the spifileinfo object, regex is not something i advise to use for getting an extension

Comment: @Chayan its the one for sending email thats not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are getting the file extension is not good at all. You are subtracting the last 4 character from file name but what about `.docx`? Do you think it will return as others? You should use `pathinfo` to get file extension.

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);// will return doc/docx ect. without the leading dot(.).
```

So change your code like this(hope this should work):

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0){

    function validateInput($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;   
    }

    $file_name = validateInput($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $temp_name = validateInput($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    //get file extension
    $extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    //allowed file types
    $allowed_extensions = array("doc", "docx", "pdf", "png");

    //check if uploaded file is allowed
    if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)){

        ....

    } else {
        echo "<script>
        alert('file format not allowed');
        </script>";
    }

} else {
   echo "<script>
   alert('no file selected');
   </script>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your input works fine and allowed me to realise that its the if statement for the email part thats not working....can you please help me look into it?

Comment: remove `$headers` from mail function and try. If it works than problem is in your  `$headers`.@Wale

Comment: i took of the empty "" and it now sends, the problem now is the attachment which is now sent as pure text within the body of the email

Answer (score 0):

you can slipt the filename into array and check the last value of array with end($arr) and compare with extension array using in_array. Hope this might help you.